# Outlook 2016 shows an empty inbox after sending emails

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, email, microsoft-outlook

We have a shared inbox that we use. There are two users that access this and both are reporting that after writing/sending a new email, the inbox shows no emails in it. They have to go to another folder then back to the root inbox and all the emails are back there that should be.

We've tried resetting the view of the inbox to see if there's a setting that could be hiding items, but nothing seems to make it stay permanently. Additionally, it is semi-random that this happens. They could send 5 emails and on the last one everything disappears, but the other 4 were fine.

Answer (score 0):

1.Check if any client/server side transport rule result in the inbound messages are delivered to other folder/recipients.
2.Switch the Outlook mode to Online mode, then check the result.
3.For the shared folder, unselect 'download shared folders'
[image]
4.Verify no filter on view settings.

[enter link description here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/1709-outlook-remove-filter-applied.html)

5.Reset the views for the entire mailbox. Close Outlook. Go to Start menu > Run and type 'Outlook.exe /cleanviews' then click OK. 
6. perform a update with Office. Then check if this issue persists:

[enter link description here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2625547/how-to-install-the-latest-applicable-updates-for-microsoft-outlook-us)

Comment: The solution for this turned out to be a misconfiguration in O365. There was a cloud exchange email proviosned for the user as well as an on prem email.